# ExtraReducers don't see and change state in authSlice and notifySlice. I use thunk called 'login' to login and call notify actions. What can I do?

Tags: reactjs, slice, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

**My notifySlice**

*State have to be changed here but it doesn't. ExtraReducers don't see and change state in authSlice and notifySlice. I use thunk called 'login' to login and call notify actions. I also tried to use builder and return instead of 'state = action.payload etc'.State doesn't highlight in extraReducers. How to make it right and not using dispatch in standard thunk function?*

```
const notifySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'alert',
    initialState: {},
    reducers: {
        alert(state, action) {
            state = action.payload
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [login.pending]: (state) => {
            console.log(state)
            state = {loading: true}
        },
        [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            console.log(state)
            console.log(action.payload)
            state = {success: action.payload.msg}
        },
        [login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            console.log(action.payload)
            state = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const {alert} = notifySlice.actions
export default notifySlice.reducer
```

**My authSlice**

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: {},
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state = {
                token: action.payload.accessToken,
                user: action.payload.user
            }
        }
    }
})

export default authSlice.reducer
```

**My login asyncThunk**

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/login',
    async (data, {rejectWithValue}) => {
        try {
            const res = await postDataAPI('auth/login', data)
            localStorage.setItem('firstLogin', 'true')
            return res
        } catch (err) {
            rejectWithValue({error: err.response.data.msg})
        }
    }
)
```

**Image of React App with Redux devtools**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLRme.png

Answer (score 1):

In RTK Reducers, you can modify the object that is in state, but you cannot reassign the variable. So instead of `state = foo` you have to do `return foo`. See [Writing Reducers with Immer - Resetting and Replacing State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state)

Also, you will have to `return rejectWithValue(...)` - it needs the `return`.